# Run a report on 10 databases using Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have multiple databases in SQL Server as shown in the picture below:
[DBs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C905S.jpg)

I have created a report in Report Builder 3.o and it running well without errors.
Now i want to include all my databases in the data sources (shown by the question mark) as shown bellow:
[Report Builder 3.0 data sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoWC1.jpg)

The idea is to have the data in this report comming from all my databases.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect to a single server and database as normal and reference each database using a fully qualified name.

If you want to include data from all the databases and treat them as a single table then you can just union them together.

For example, you might create a dataset query that looks something like this.

```
SELECT 'AAG' as DbName, EmployeeName, Department, Salary FROM AAG.mySchema.myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABZ', EmployeeName, Department, Salary FROM ABZ.mySchema.myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AFG', EmployeeName, Department, Salary FROM AFG.mySchema.myTable
```

Here I have also included a column to identify where the data came from in case you need to know this later.

Comment: where do i put that SELECT stament in report builder ? Where are those table comming from ?

Comment: The select statement goes in your dataset query. The takes I just made up. I have no idea what your actual takes are called

Comment: i need it in report buider, in the connecting string. To include more than one database there.

Comment: As I said, connection is to a single database but you can access all all the other databases from there. You cannot set connection to more than one dB but you don't need to

Comment: Correction on my earlier comment takes=tables! (Auto-correct on my phone)